# How do I run multiple functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to learn Javascript and struggling! I have got my head around CSS & HTML to an ok level and have made a very basic file to help me learn basic Javascript functions. I just want to know if what I am doing is on the right path? I want to click on the different color boxes and change the main box. 
I have made a fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/Margate/mN9hs/

This should be self explanatory. Nothing that will ever be used I just want to learn with it!
After hours trying to work it out I am completely stuck as to why it is not working!
Thank you very much for any help / guidance....

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Learning Page!</title>

<style type="text/css">
#MainContent{position: relative; margin: 0px auto; top: 10px; border: 2px solid black; width: 500px; height: 250px;}
#ChangeThis{position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50px; width: 400px; height: 100px; background-color: red; border: 2px solid black;}
#ColourBoxContiner{position: absolute; left: 99px; top: 120px; width: 302px; height: 102px; border: 1px solid black;}
#RedBox{position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;}
#YellowBox {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;}
#GreenBox {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 200px; width: 100px; height:     100px;     background-color: green; border: 1px solid black; cursor: pointer;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="MainContent">
    <div id="ChangeThis"></div>
    <div id="ColourBoxContiner">
        <div id = "RedBox" onclick="ChangeColorOne()"></div>
        <div id = "YellowBox" onclick="ChangeColorTwo()"></div>
        <div id = "GreenBox" onclick="ChangeColorThree()"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function ChangeColorOne() {
    document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style="background.color:orange";
}
function ChangeColorTwo() {
    document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style="background.color:black";
}
function ChangeColorThree() {
    document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style="background.color:blue";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a typo error: document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style="background.color:blue" is wrong, use document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor = "blue" instead.

Comment: What are the "multiple functions" you're trying to run? Each of your click handlers just runs one function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle won't work (or won't for me on chrome) while you have the JavaScript set as `onLoad`, try `No wrap - in <head>` and you've a little syntax error in your JavaScript. Apart from that you were very close.

eg.

```
function ChangeColorOne() {
    document.getElementById("ChangeThis").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}
```

See this updated version on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mN9hs/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time Klors.

Answer (score 3):

When you are setting the background color you should be using "backgroundColor" without the period, like this:

```
function ChangeColorOne()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="orange";}

function ChangeColorTwo()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="black";}

function ChangeColorThree()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="blue";}
```

BTW, [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is a great place to go to learn Javascript. You can also use [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much DRock Miller. Codeacademy is a good one. I will use this site a lot...

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style="background.color:orange";`

->

`document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor = "orange";`

Answer (score 1):

Stop using HTML onclick attributes and bind the click events through JS. The structure is `yourElement.addEventListener("click", yourfunction);` if your function is available in the scope. If you assign more than one, and you do not prevent your event from bubbling, all your observers will get the message.

Comment: Hello Sebastien is it better that I learn event listeners then? I think I need to just go back to my courses! I have been learning this for months now but am still not any good at it! Thank you for your help...

Comment: The title of the question is slightly misleading. The author isn't trying to bind multiple event handlers of the same event type for a single element. Side note: `addEventListener` isn't supported by IE8 and earlier (if that matters).

Comment: @margate: I have only supplied half of the solution. The event listener, when triggered, will have the element that triggered it as `this`. You can therefore easily change its color and thus reduce your four functions to one (possibly with an if statement in it).

Comment: Thanks for your help Sebastien, I will go back to my tutorials as I do not fully understand everything. I guess I just need to keep on learning....

Answer (score 1):

Okay buddy [here](http://i.guibench.com/snippet/ag9zfmd1aWJlbmNoYWxwaGFyDwsSB1Byb2plY3QYiqECDA) is your snippet in working condition.

Actually you need to do as:

```
function ChangeColorOne()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="orange";}

function ChangeColorTwo()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="black";}

function ChangeColorThree()
{document.getElementById('ChangeThis').style.backgroundColor="blue";}


ChangeColorOne();
ChangeColorTwo();
ChangeColorThree(); // call them all
```

Have a look. Hope it will help you =) .